# .NET wcf call method freezes

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a problem with a WCF service method call that freeze and doesn't return a response **if connection is done on the same process**...

Here is the full code (very simplified to show only what is needed):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestProject
{

    [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(IBaseServiceCallback))]
    public interface IBaseService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool IsServiceInitiated();
    }

    public interface IBaseServiceCallback
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool IsClientInitiated();
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, AutomaticSessionShutdown = false, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class BaseService : IBaseService
    {
        public bool IsServiceInitiated()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, AutomaticSessionShutdown = false, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class BaseServiceCallback : IBaseServiceCallback
    {
        public bool IsClientInitiated()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class CustomServer
    {
        private BaseService service;
        private ServiceHost host;

        public bool IsStarted
        {
            get { return host != null && host.State == CommunicationState.Opened; }
        }

        public CustomServer()
        {
            service = new BaseService();
            host = new ServiceHost(service, new Uri[] { new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:7780") });

            Type interfaceType = typeof(IBaseService);

            // Create service end point
            ServiceEndpoint endpointPipe = host.AddServiceEndpoint(interfaceType, new NetTcpBinding(), "CustomService");

            // Define TCP binding
            NetTcpBinding bindingPipe = (NetTcpBinding)endpointPipe.Binding;
            bindingPipe.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 5000000;
            bindingPipe.MaxBufferPoolSize = 5000000;
            bindingPipe.MaxBufferSize = 5000000;
            bindingPipe.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2048;
            bindingPipe.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
            bindingPipe.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
            bindingPipe.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;

            // Increase MaxItemsInObjectGraph for all operations behaviors
            foreach (OperationDescription op in endpointPipe.Contract.Operations)
            {
                var dataContractBehavior = op.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();

                if (dataContractBehavior != null)
                {
                    dataContractBehavior.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue;
                }
            }

            // In order to publish the service contract, it is important to publish the metadata
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();

            if (smb == null)
            {
                smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            }

            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;

            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            // Add MEX endpoint
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(), "net.tcp://localhost:7780/IDMmex");
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            // Open for listening
            host.Open();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            // Stop listening
            host.Close();
        }
    }

    public class CustomClient
    {
        public IBaseService ServiceProxy { get; private set; }
        private BaseServiceCallback callback;

        public CustomClient()
        {
            callback = new BaseServiceCallback();
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            string serviceUrl = "net.tcp://localhost:7780/CustomService";

            // Create a channel in order to find the exact call back type.
            DuplexChannelFactory<IBaseService> sampleChannel = new DuplexChannelFactory<IBaseService>(callback, new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl));

            Type duplexChannelFactory = typeof(DuplexChannelFactory<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { typeof(IBaseService) });

            object pipeFactory = Activator.CreateInstance(duplexChannelFactory, new object[] { callback, new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl) });

            // Get the service end point
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint = (ServiceEndpoint)duplexChannelFactory.GetProperty("Endpoint").GetValue(pipeFactory, null);

            // Configure TCP binding
            NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = (NetTcpBinding)endpoint.Binding;
            tcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 5000000;
            tcpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 5000000;
            tcpBinding.MaxBufferSize = 5000000;
            tcpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2048;
            tcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
            tcpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;
            tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
            tcpBinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            tcpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            tcpBinding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            tcpBinding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;

            // Increase MaxItemsInObjectGraph for all operations behaviors
            foreach (OperationDescription op in endpoint.Contract.Operations)
            {
                var dataContractBehavior = op.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();

                if (dataContractBehavior != null)
                {
                    dataContractBehavior.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue;
                }
            }

            // Create the channel to retrieve the pipe proxy object
            MethodInfo method = duplexChannelFactory.GetMethod("CreateChannel", new Type[0]);
            object pipeProxyObject = method.Invoke(pipeFactory, new object[] { });

            // Set the service proxy with the retrieved pipe proxy object
            ServiceProxy = (IBaseService)pipeProxyObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I have a Windows Forms application that initiate a CustomServer, a CustomClient and that try to communicate:

```
CustomClient customClient = new CustomClient();
CustomServer customServer = new CustomServer();
customServer.Start();
customClient.Connect();

if (customClient.ServiceProxy.IsServiceInitiated()) // FREEZE HERE !!
{
    MessageBox.Show("Server initiated");
}
```

The connection is done, but when the "IsServiceInitiated" method is called, the application freezes.

But if a create an application dedicated for starting a server, and another application dedicated to a client that connect to the server, the method doesn't freeze and return true.

Any help is really needed.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:
OK, I added a message inspector and dispatch inspector and output results of BeforeSendRequest and AfterReceiveRequest in the console. Here is the result:

```
Before send request: Action = http://tempuri.org/IBaseService/IsServiceInitiated Reply = 
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IBaseService/IsServiceInitiated</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:d14b0af4-81c3-46c7-9b38-83a8fb092028</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPoy1+4Je4rwBHkZsB8NCWGqQAAAAAAM8Ng9k570ayit0OK365Vn8yY2g0amdHlrkBcRNGylUACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <IsServiceInitiated xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

After receive request: Action = http://tempuri.org/IBaseService/IsServiceInitiated Reply = 
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IBaseService/IsServiceInitiated</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:d14b0af4-81c3-46c7-9b38-83a8fb092028</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPoy1+4Je4rwBHkZsB8NCWGqQAAAAAAM8Ng9k570ayit0OK365Vn8yY2g0amdHlrkBcRNGylUACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">net.tcp://localhost:7780/CustomService</a:To>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <IsServiceInitiated xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    </IsServiceInitiated>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I waited on the freezed method and finally got a CommunicationException:
The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error

NEW EDIT:

Amazing!!!
When using a separated application starting the server and the first application connect a client to this server, It works and the message inspector doesn't launch me the AfterReceiveRequest event, but I get the BeforeReceiveReply output :

```
Before receive reply: Action = http://tempuri.org/IBaseService/IsServiceInitiatedResponse Reply = 
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IBaseService/IsServiceInitiatedResponse</a:Action>
    <a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:bc055419-68d6-4f08-8170-0d1097e11d39</a:RelatesTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:To>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <IsServiceInitiatedResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <IsServiceInitiatedResult>true</IsServiceInitiatedResult>
    </IsServiceInitiatedResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

EDIT AGAIN:
I notice that my service works perfectly if the server host is opened before a Windows Form is displayed ("Show" method), but if the host in opened after any Windows Form is displayed or within the constructor of a Windows Form, the WCF method call freeze....... Very strange...

Comment: what happens if you create and open your serviceHost on a different thread?  Do things work?  What about on a different AppDomain?

Comment: That is the solution, but I don't understand why I can't start the host and communicate with it in the synchronisation context of a form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I don't know exactely why this happens in this specific case with Windows Forms, but i have to start the server on a separated thread.
So I add in my form constructor this change:

```
CustomClient customClient = new CustomClient();
CustomServer customServer = new CustomServer();

Exception serverStartException = null;

System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    try
    {
        customServer.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        serverStartException = e;
    }
}

int maxTries = 5;
int currentTry = 0;

while (!customServer.IsStarted && currentTry < maxTries && serverStartException == null)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    currentTry++;
}

if (serverStartException != null)
{
    throw new Exception("The server couldn't start", serverStartException );
}
else if (!customServer.IsStarted)
{
    throw new Exception("The server couldn't start for unknown reason");
}

customClient.Connect();

if (customClient.ServiceProxy.IsServiceInitiated())
{
    MessageBox.Show("Server initiated");
}
```

And it's now working !!

If anyone knows why there is this behavior, I'm really interested.

Thanks

Comment: Don't do the while (!isStarted) thing ... its nasty, hacky, and horrible :)  Use a ManualResetEvent instead.  Also, give it some timeout and throw if it fails to start within the allotted time frame.

The reason why this works is very likely due to the synchronizationContext of WPF.  Unfortunately without a full dump there's no way to know what's causing this to happen.

Comment: Effectively, I wrote a simple code but in fact, I added a max try counter to throw an exception if the server didn't start after sleeping X times, but I'll have a look to the ManualResetEvent because I didn't know this trick.

Answer (score 1):

Open up the host before the base window is initialized. This way the host will not associate itself with the form's SynchronizationContext and will run on a separate thread.

e.g:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(BaseService));
host.Open();

Application.Run(new BaseForm()); // already exists
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have several issues with your code.  The binding settings have issues, your service definition and interfaces have problems, etc.

Below is a working copy based off your code.  Make sure you adjust the bindings properly.

If this doesn't fix your issue, could you please paste the client callstack?

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CustomServer server = new CustomServer();
            server.Open();

            CustomClient client = new CustomClient();
            client.Connect();

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter");
            Console.ReadLine();

            server.Close();
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IBaseServiceCallback))]
    public interface IBaseService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool IsServiceInitiated();
    }

    public interface IBaseServiceCallback
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void TheCallback(string str);
    }

    //Change3
    //[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, AutomaticSessionShutdown = false, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    [CallbackBehavior]
    public class BaseServiceCallback : IBaseServiceCallback
    {
        public void TheCallback(string str)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, AutomaticSessionShutdown = false, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class BaseService : IBaseService
    {
        public bool IsServiceInitiated()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class CustomServer
    {
        private BaseService service;
        private ServiceHost host;

        public bool IsStarted
        {
            get { return host != null && host.State == CommunicationState.Opened; }
        }

        public CustomServer()
        {
            service = new BaseService();
            host = new ServiceHost(service, new Uri[] { new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:7780") });

            Type interfaceType = typeof(IBaseService);

            // Create service end point
            ServiceEndpoint endpointPipe = host.AddServiceEndpoint(interfaceType, new NetTcpBinding(), "CustomService");

            // Define TCP binding
            NetTcpBinding bindingPipe = (NetTcpBinding)endpointPipe.Binding;

            //Change1
            //bindingPipe.MaxReceivedMessageSize = long.MaxValue;
            //bindingPipe.MaxBufferPoolSize = long.MaxValue;
            //bindingPipe.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;

            //bindingPipe.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2048;
            //bindingPipe.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
            //bindingPipe.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
            //bindingPipe.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;

            // Increase MaxItemsInObjectGraph for all operations behaviors
            foreach (OperationDescription op in endpointPipe.Contract.Operations)
            {
                var dataContractBehavior = op.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();

                if (dataContractBehavior != null)
                {
                    dataContractBehavior.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue;
                }
            }

            // In order to publish the service contract, it is important to publish the metadata
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();

            if (smb == null)
            {
                smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            }

            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;

            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            // Add MEX endpoint
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(), "net.tcp://localhost:7780/IDMmex");
        }

        public void Open()
        {
            if (host != null)
            {
                host.Open();
            }
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            if (host != null)
            {
                host.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    public class CustomClient
    {
        private IBaseService serviceProxy;
        private BaseServiceCallback callback;

        public CustomClient()
        {
            callback = new BaseServiceCallback();
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            string serviceUrl = "net.tcp://localhost:7780/CustomService";

            // Create a channel in order to find the exact call back type.
            DuplexChannelFactory<IBaseService> sampleChannel = new DuplexChannelFactory<IBaseService>(callback, new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl));

            Type duplexChannelFactory = typeof(DuplexChannelFactory<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { typeof(IBaseService) });

            object pipeFactory = Activator.CreateInstance(duplexChannelFactory, new object[] { callback, new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl) });

            // Get the service end point
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint = (ServiceEndpoint)duplexChannelFactory.GetProperty("Endpoint").GetValue(pipeFactory, null);

            // Configure TCP binding
            //NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = (NetTcpBinding)endpoint.Binding;
            //tcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = long.MaxValue;
            //tcpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = long.MaxValue;
            //tcpBinding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            //tcpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2048;
            //tcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
            //tcpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;
            //tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
            //tcpBinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            //tcpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            //tcpBinding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            //tcpBinding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;

            // Increase MaxItemsInObjectGraph for all operations behaviors
            foreach (OperationDescription op in endpoint.Contract.Operations)
            {
                var dataContractBehavior = op.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();

                if (dataContractBehavior != null)
                {
                    dataContractBehavior.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue;
                }
            }

            //serviceProxy = sampleChannel.CreateChannel();

            // Create the channel to retrieve the pipe proxy object
            MethodInfo method = duplexChannelFactory.GetMethod("CreateChannel", new Type[0]);
            object pipeProxyObject = method.Invoke(pipeFactory, new object[] { });

            // Set the service proxy with the retrieved pipe proxy object
            serviceProxy = (IBaseService)pipeProxyObject;

            //Change2
            ((IChannel)serviceProxy).Open();

            // FREEZE HERE...
            bool isServerInitiated = serviceProxy.IsServiceInitiated();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I corrected because in fact, I didn't test this simplified code. See the end of my question, I specified that with two applications, one for the server and one for the client, there is no problem. Effectively, I corrected NetTcpBinding to ensure it works. If needed, I can share the complete project...

Comment: I tried your modification (no NetTcpBinding configuration and on client connect, convert the service proxy to IChannel and call the "Open" method) but the IsServiceInitiated method call still freeze...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your request. How do I retrieve the client callstack ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: OK, I added a message inspector and dispatch inspector and output results of BeforeSendRequest and AfterReceiveRequest in the console: